# Find all references in VS 2013 Pro not an option anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I used to be able to right click and select find all references for a method or something and then that box would open and show me all of the places in my code where it was being used. All of the sudden if I right click I no longer get that option.

Comment: I think this question don't belong to Stackoverflow, maybe Stackexchange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still in all recent versions of Visual Studio. <kbd>Cntl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,  <kbd>R</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut. If it's not appearing in your context menu, it is something specific to your VS configuration/settings.

You can edit your context menu's by the following:

1. Goto Tools->Customize
2. Select the Commands tab
3. Select the Context menu radio button
4. Select the appropriate context menu from the dropdown list to the right: (`Editor Context Menus | Code Window` or `Other Context Menus | Code Window`)
5. Add or delete context menu items as desired.

When adding a context menu command, the Find All References command is located under the Edit section.